# Plotting multiple random effects in single plot mixed models

Tags: r, lme4, sjplot

```
library("lme4")
data(sleepstudy)             

fit1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

To visualise the random effect,

```
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(fit1,type = "re",facet.grid = FALSE)
```

In my orginal data, I have three random groups. However, if I want to plot the random effects, they all come in three separate plots. How can I put them in all single plot in 1 X 3 panel or 3 X 1 panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`

```
fit1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ (1|Days) + (1|Subject), sleepstudy) 

library(sjPlot)
p <- plot_model(fit1, type = "re", facet.grid=FALSE) 

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p[[1]], p[[2]])
```

***Produces:***

[image]

You also could consider `lattice::qqmath()`.

```
library(lattice)
p2 <- qqmath(ranef(fit1, condVar=TRUE))
grid.arrange(p2[[1]], p2[[2]])
```

***Produces:***

[image]

***Note:*** To specify the columns use the `ncol` option. Compare e.g. `grid.arrange(p2[[1]], p2[[2]], ncol=2)` vs. `grid.arrange(p2[[1]], p2[[2]], ncol=1)`.

Comment: There is also a small wrapper around `grid.arrange()` in sjPlot: `plot_grid()`. So, `plot_model(fit1,type = "re") %>% plot_grid()` results in the same output.